# Iterating and binding a List with JSTL

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a list of Coordinate objects:

```
public class Coordinate {

    Integer id;
    Integer x;
    Integer y;

}
```

```
    <form:input path="myList[${elemIndex}].x"   size="5"    />
                                                                                               </c:forEach>
```

But I got this error

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'myList[javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@a6dfb0]' of bean class [MyForm]: Invalid index in property path 'myList[javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@a6dfb0]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@a6dfb0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<form:input path="myList[${elemIndex.index}].x" size="5" />
```

Assuming that `elemIndex` is what you set to `varStatus` attribute in `c:forEach`.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696974/modelattribute-not-working-with-lists-in-spring/26698854#26698854).